# Confused about "he might have gone"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, tense, modal-verbs

Let's take two sentences.

1. **He went there**.
2. **He has gone there**.

One is simple past and the other is present perfect. Now if we want to add probability in these two sentences.

*He might have gone there*.

Which tense does it refer to ?
Is it the first one or the second one ?

Answer (score 3):

You're thinking about things in the wrong order.

Here is the "right" way: Take two sentences.  "He will go there", "He might go there". The first is about a certain future, and the second is about a possible future.

But what if we want to talk about the past.  You can change the first into two different "past" tenses:  The simple past tense "He went there" and the present perfect "He has gone there".

But you can't put the second into the simple past tense, because the modal verb "might" doesn't have a past tense.  It is "defective".  You can, however, use perfective to talk about past possibility "He might have gone there"

That sentence doesn't "refer", but as it is the only way to talk about the past with the modal "might" you can add a time phrase "He might have gone there last week", just like you can say "He went there last week".

On the other hand, you can't add a time phrase to form *"He has gone there last week."  That is incorrect.

The various "modal+have" constructions can have meanings and use that idiomatically differs from simply combining the meaning of the modal with the meaning of the present perfect".

Comment: Thanks. If you see any more mistakes like that feel free to do the edit yourself.